# Bundling Angular Element into a Single File

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, web-component, angular-elements

I am building a Web Component with **Angular Element** (version 13) and I have a question regarding **bundling**.

Would it be possible to the build the Web Component in a way that all of the js bundles (main.js, runtime.js and polyfills.js) and the css and the svg icons in the /assets folder are in a **single js** file at the end?

What I am doing right now is running  `ng build --configuration element --output-hashing none && node build.js` where build.js includes is:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const concat = require('concat');

(async function build() {
  const files = [
    './dist/runtime.js',
    './dist/polyfills.js',
    './dist/main.js'
  ];

  await concat(files, './dist/webcomp-ecar-friendly-accommodations.min.js');
  await fs.remove('./dist/runtime.js')
  await fs.remove('./dist/polyfills.js')
  await fs.remove('./dist/main.js')
})();
```

Is there a way to bundle also the css file and the /assets in the same js bundle? I do know it is done with Webpack in other applications but I am not sure how to do that with the Angular CLI.

Any input would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you look into this.
`ngx-build-plus` https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-build-plus

Comment: I have, the --single-bundle option does not help, and still produces separate bundles

Comment: just concat js files into one file